# how do i get this to pull the closest number to the avg?

Tags: mysql

I started with the subqueries, so that I could obtain the total sales for each specific month. I then took each of those responses and nested it into one statement.

I then created the main query wich added the totals from each month then divided by 5, giving me the mystical average monthly sales.

I then had the query give the total sales for each month so that it could be compared to the average.

```
 (SELECT 
    ROUND(SUM(a.total_monthly_sales + b.total_monthly_sales + c.total_monthly_sales + d.total_monthly_sales + e.total_monthly_sales) / 5,
            2) AS avg_monthly_sales,
    a.total_monthly_sales AS april,
    b.total_monthly_sales AS may,
    c.total_monthly_sales AS june,
    d.total_monthly_sales AS july,
    e.total_monthly_sales AS august
 FROM
    (SELECT 
        SUM(invoice_total) AS total_monthly_sales,
            date_format(invoice_date, '%m-%y') AS 'mm-yy'
    FROM
        `ap`.`invoices`
    WHERE
        invoice_date BETWEEN '2011-04-01' AND '2011-04-31') a
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        SUM(invoice_total) AS total_monthly_sales,
            date_format(invoice_date, '%m-%y') AS 'mm-yy'
    FROM
        `ap`.`invoices`
    WHERE
        invoice_date BETWEEN '2011-05-01' AND '2011-05-31') b
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        SUM(invoice_total) AS total_monthly_sales,
            date_format(invoice_date, '%m-%y') AS 'mm-yy'
    FROM
        `ap`.`invoices`
    WHERE
        invoice_date BETWEEN '2011-06-01' AND '2011-06-31') c
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        SUM(invoice_total) AS total_monthly_sales,
            date_format(invoice_date, '%m-%y') AS 'mm-yy'
    FROM
        `ap`.`invoices`
    WHERE
        invoice_date BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-07-31') d
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        SUM(invoice_total) AS total_monthly_sales,
            date_format(invoice_date, '%m-%y') AS 'mm-yy'
    FROM
        `ap`.`invoices`
    WHERE
        invoice_date BETWEEN '2011-08-01' AND '2011-08-31') e)t1
```

How do i get it to only show the avg and the month closest to it?